# Create and store arrays in for loop

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and I have some problem with memory allocation.

```
vector<int *> V;  

for(int i=0;i<3;i++){   
    int A[3];    
    cin>>A[0]>>A[1]>>A[2];  
    V.push_back(A);
}

for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    cout<<V[i][0]<<V[i][1]<<V[i][2]<<endl;
}
```

I want to create arrays and push them into vector as below. But if I input

```
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

The output will be

```
3 3 3
3 3 3
3 3 3
```

If I replace `int A[3]` with `int *A=new int()` then I get the right answer. I want to know why?

Comment: you are storing a reference(through a pointer) to a local array

Comment: and that reference is not valid after execution of ending brace of for loop

Comment: yes I think I get the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `int A[3];` you are invoking undefined behaviour because the array you are storing in the vector goes out of scope after the loop.

If you use `int *A = new int();`, you are allocating one integer, and then using three, which is also invoking undefined behaviour.

You should be using `int *A = new int[3];` or thereabouts to allocate an array of three `int`.

---

In the cold light of morning, the `int *A = new int[3];` solution leaks horribly.  The vector destructor doesn't know it needs to free the sub-arrays.

The diagnosis of the trouble remains accurate; the appropriate remedy needs rethinking.

I need to work on what the correct (leak-free) solution is — and I've got other things to do right now.  One plausible option is `vector< vector<int> >`, but I've not coded that up so it works yet.

Comment: I am still confused about the difference between `int A[3]` and `int *A=new int[3]`. I think they both allocate memory for 3 integer to the pointer A??

Comment: @user3404498 Yes, `int A[3]` allocate memory, but because of the life time of var `A[3]`, the memory will be deallocated when goes out of the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Although their both generate a array with 3 element, their memory space are maintained in different behave.

int A[3] will generate a local array which will be destroyed after loop.  Hence, the array in the vector is destroyed and you will get a strange result.

For int *A=new int[3], the array will not be destroyed until the delete operator is used. Hence all data in the vector will be hold corrected.

Comment: nice!I thoroughly understand this issue/